# Android studio doesn't recognize the running emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

When I run my app from AndroidStudio 0.4.3 using `Run` I see `Choose Device` which has two sections `choose a running device` or `Launch Emulator`. I don't have a running emulator at the moment so I click the `...` to launch AVD manager and start an emulator. At this point I see that under `choose a running device` the emulator I just launched shows up but its listed as `offline`.

In the past the `offline` status went away when the emulator was fully up and running. However, now I've noticed that when the emulator is launched fully, it no longer appears in `choose a running device`.

I feel like I'm always playing cat and mouse game with android studio picking up the emulator. Is there a better way to do this? Am I missing something?

Comment: try to kill-server then type adb start-server commands

Comment: If kill-server/start-server does not work, try terminating **ALL** running adb instances, then click the **Android** tab in Android Studio (this should restart ADB). If this still does not work it could be that AS and your AVD use different ADB instances - make sure that your `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` environment variable is set and that AS uses the same SDK as set for the environment variable.

Answer (score 42):

Disable and then Enable **ADB Integration**

In Android Studio go to

1. Menu -> Tools
2. Android
3. Enable ADB Integration (should be checked, click to remove check)
4. Enable ADB Integration (should not be checked, click to add check)

Run your app again.  Emulator that was previously missing from Run dialog should be available to be selected upon which to run your app.

Comment: This menu isn't there in 3.5 and I don't think has been for a while.

Answer (score 29):

Try to kill the adb server and restart it.

Locate your adb binary (linux/osx) or adb.exe (windows) and do:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

this should fix your problem

Even if your problem still not solved then **Restart emulator**.

Comment: Linux user here, didn't fix my issue. Any alternative?

Answer (score 7):

Wipe Data and restarting emulator helped me, hope this helps to someone.

[image]

Comment: This work form me, my emulator running full but i cant selected a device and this solve the problem

Comment: Does not work if your problem is that when the emulator is running it is not being recognized as running by the IDE.

Answer (score 3):

inside AVD manager, select your virtual devices, then 1 stop, 2 wipe user data, 3 cold reboot, works for me.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, running Android Studio with administrator permissions can help (in addition to restarting adb server).

Answer (score 1):

Unchecking the "Enable ADB " worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1) it helped me to cold boot the device.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add -port 5037 on ../[some_emulator]/emu-launch-params.txt file & try again...

like image

[image]