# Cannot see running emulated device

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio (0.5.5) on OSX to try and run an app I'm working on, when the dialog appears to select a running device or launch a new emulator, the running device doesn't appear in the list, it does appear in the Android Device Manager though from the Tools | Android menu.

I've tried kill-server, start-server as suggested here [Android studio doesn't recognize the running emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540948/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-the-running-emulator) but that hasn't worked either.

Comment: When you click on the `Android Device Manager` does it have a green check next to the name?

Comment: @AndyGable, Yes it has a green tick, and the emulator starts up fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't add comments since I don't have enough reputation so I'll have to answer a little blind here. This is actually dependent on the OS and device manufacturer. If you are on linux, you need to just edit the udev rules. I had this same issue when working with a galaxy nexus, and I got the answer for running it on Ubuntu from the "[Using hardware devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)" section of the Android dev guide.

Comment: It's not a connected device, it's the emulator that it can't see.