# Android studio: emulator is running but not showing up in Run App "choose a running device"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have launched my emulator via the AVD manager and once it's running I have clicked on `run app`. I have waited a couple of minutes for my running device to show up in `choose a running device` but the window always stays blank.

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Probably the project you are running is not compatible **(API version/Hardware requirements)** with the emulator settings. Check in your `build.gradle` file if the ***targetSDK*** and ***minimumSdk*** version is lower or equal to the sdk version of your Emulator.

You should also uncheck **Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration**

If your case is different then restart your Android Studio and run the emulator again.

Comment: My build.gradle indicates `minSdkVersion 15` and `targetSdkVersion 22` . My emulator runs on API 21

Comment: Great! make the `targetSdkVersion` = 21 and sync your gradle.
Then it should work!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I changed `targetSdkVersion` to 21 but I am still getting the same blank window.

Comment: I have unchecked `Enable ADB Integration` and my emulator does show up now!

Comment: Great!! I am adding this additional information in my given answer, so that other people can find it. :)

Comment: Menu -> Tools -> Android -> Enable ADB Integration. This works! Thank you all!!

Comment: If this solution doesn't work, it means you don't haved installed Adb driver of your device. Check if your adb driver is installed or not. @RohitBandil

Comment: @MohammadArman, I did uncheck, but still the adb doesn't show up the emulator. Couldn't work for last few days, what else to do? please help.. :(

Comment: Sometimes it also shows the emulator in unchecked status, but doesn't run the app, showing error that app can't be run with unchecking that option.

Comment: I cannot find Tools -> Android ?

Answer (score 13):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540948/android-studio-doesnt-recognize-the-running-emulator) helped me to solve my problem, in particular this answer:

- In Android Studio go to Menu -> Tools
- Android
- Uncheck Enable ADB Integration

Comment: Cannot find these in Android Studio

Answer (score 7):

Had similar issue with my emulator.
Solved by **Wiping Data** of emulator

**Tool > ABD Manager >** Down arrow under **Action** **Wipe Data**

*Note : This is remove all data inside emulator.*

Answer (score 5):

My emulator used to suddenly disappear but the app still continues to run.

Solution-
Open task manager and kill qemu-system (Under Android Studio). This will stop the emulator. Then restart emulator.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else having the issue - none of the answers provided worked for me.

My case may be different to others but I had `Android Studio` installed first which installs the SDK by default to: `C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk`. We then decided to use Xamarin for our projects, so Xamarin was installed and installed an additional SDK by default, located here: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk`.

Changing Xamarin to match the same SDK path worked for me which I did in the registry (although through the VS settings I'd guess it's the same):

`\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Android SDK Tools\Path`

Change the path to match the `Android Studio` SDK path, close everything, start the VS Emulator, run Android Studio, ensure `ADB integration` is off and try. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you uncheck the ADB Integration, you cannot use the debug any more.You may just restart the adb server, run

```
$adb kill-server
$adb start-server
```

in Terminal to restart the adb server without restarting the Android Studio. Then the emulator shows up.

Comment: says command adb not found

Comment: @ShamsulArefin pls check https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb, if you installed android SDK, make sure the *android_sdk/platform-tools/* path is in your shell's PATH variable.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Wipe the data of your Android virtual Device and then start the emulator. Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is not proposing a solution. Just a workaround in case someone is looking**

I am using Idea based Android Studio (some people are talking about eclipse one here)

When I launch the app in the emulator (using the Run App button of Android Studio) AVD shows up but the app does not launch or run.

However when I connect my mobile and launch the app on my mobile the App works (this itself took some time, enabling developer options on mobile and doing the right configuration)

- Because My app is launching on connected mobile, I can say nothing wrong with App.
- There is some problem with AVD integration which I could not figure out so **As of now I am working around my problem following way.**

1 - I installed the app manually by dragging the APK file on AVD. (APK file is app\build\outputs\apk\debug folder)

2 - Then my AVD was not showing the installed APP list.
3 - I searched my APP using Google bar on AVD and dragged the APP icon on the home screen of AVD.

4 - I can now launch the APP using my APP icon on the home screen of AVD.

**That's how I am working around my problem. **

I have verified that Run App Icon does install the Application. Installation, not launching, appears to be the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your adb connection is broken.

close eclipse

open cmd-prompt type adb kill-server then adb start-server

reopen eclipse

run the project!

Comment: I tried this a couple of time but still the device doesn't show up

Comment: System restart also helps me sometimes in resolving this issue.. Also are you running emulator first time on system or it worked before?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a brand new computer, and the reason was simple. Although I downloaded and unzipped the Android SDK, I didn't add it to the `PATH`. So:

On Windows, you have to launch `envvar` and there, add the path to your `android/platform-tools`

On MacOS, edit the `.zshrc` file in your home, and add
`export PATH="$PATH:/your/own/path/to/android/platform-tools"`

Answer (score -1):

try to open the emulator and run it parallel with android studio/eclipse and the option will be displayed to select in the choose the device(emuator name, mine is Genymotion).

Answer (score -2):

1. start device from genymotion button (have to install genymotion before and setup genymotion folder location on settings)
2. run application
3. choose genymotion running  device

Answer (score -2):

Check the android path of the emulator.

I had to change the registry in here:

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > WOW6432Node > Android SDK Tools
```

to the actual path of the sdk location (which can be found in android studio: settings-> System Settings -> Android SDK)

All the credit goes to the author of this blogpost [www.clearlyagileinc.com/](https://www.clearlyagileinc.com/blog/using-the-visual-studio-android-emulator-with-android-studio)

Answer (score -7):

in your device you want to run app on 
Go to **settings**
**About device** >> ***Build number*** triple clicks or more
and back to settings you will found "***Developer options***" appear
go to and click on **"USB debugging"** 
Done