# Android studio avd is running in task manager but does not show in screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I have had this problem for three days . When I run an application via android studio and choose an AVD , my emulator starts in task manager but the screen of device does not show up.

I have installed and updated and enabled HAXM.

I have created different kind of AVD (x86 - arm)

I have tried for IDE 1.5 and 2.0.0

I have deleted all my configurations

---

Starting an AVD :

[image]

[image]

Thanks for helping ...

Comment: had the same problem, the AVD was just hidden out of the screen. Do you see the opened window on your task bar?

Comment: Unfortunately , I do not see it.

Comment: how long do you wait? It needs long time until it comes up....

Comment: About 2 hour . Its not about booting , its just about the windows screen does not show up .

Comment: ok, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198327/android-studio-emulator-is-running-but-not-showing-up-in-run-app-choose-a-runn

Comment: I have seen this before .Did not work

Comment: mmm....tricky.....are you sure you are hitting the requirements(enough RAM, fast processor etc...)?

Comment: also this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16717064/emulator-in-android-studio-doesnt-start  ....but I guess you have seen it too...

Comment: Yeah , I have seen this too . 
Yes bro , I have 6 GB Ram - i5 intel .
My AVD had worked correctly before this problem .

Comment: then the only thing i can imagine would be that minSDK and/or targetSDK not matching the AVD setting....