# Emulator does not show up

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

When I click on run in android studio, the emulator does not show up. It reads "waiting for target device to come online", but the emulator does not appear. I'm looking for a solution to fix this.

Comment: goto AVD create emulator and start that emulator and run the app from android studio then select that emulator.

Comment: I tried that, didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

HAXM stands for - "Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager"
HAXM Speeds Up the Slow Android Emulator.
Download intel x86 atom system image and download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) package in Extras folder.

Or you can use GenyMotion third party emulator.
[GenyMotion](https://www.genymotion.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29198327/android-studio-emulator-is-running-but-not-showing-up-in-run-app-choose-a-runn